# Why does perl treat the string "0" as false?

Tags: perl

I found in the text that string `'0'` is equivalent to `0`, hence the condition is false in PERL.

But when I looked at the ASCII table '0' is ASCII 48. So why does perl consider string `'0'` as a value `0` in this control structure ?

```
if ('0'){
        print "Statement1 \n";
        }
 else {
        print "statement2\n";
      }
```

Comment: Should a nul character `"\0"` be false?  '0' is ASCII 48 and EBCDIC 240; if there were some other encoding where it happened to be 0, would it then be false?

Comment: Because `0` and `'0'` are equivalent. (The better question is why isn't `'0E0'` false. Efficiency?)

Answer (score 10):

Because it is specified to do so.

> The number 0, the strings '0' and '', the empty list "()", and "undef"
>   are all false in a boolean context. All other values are true.
>   Negation of a true value by "!" or "not" returns a special false
>   value. When evaluated as a string it is treated as '', but as a number, it is treated as 0.

That's the specification. The behavior conforms.

---

As for *why* the specification is so written -- Perl makes a practice of implicitly converting between strings and numbers, and in this respect does not use ASCII value but decimal value. Treating `'0'` in the same manner as `0` in this context is thus consistent with the behavior of allowing `'9'+1` to return `10`, rather than `':'` (the next ASCII value).